# Django UnicodeDecodeError only on apache/nginx

Tags: python, django, apache, utf-8, character-encoding

When

```
locale.getlocale()
locale.getdefaultlocale()
sys.getfilesystemencoding()
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

is run through `manage.py shell`, I get

```
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
utf-8
utf-8
```

Which fits my locales:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

However, when the request is handled by Apache/Nginx it produces:

```
(None, None)
(None, None)
ascii
utf-8
```

This leads to several UnicodeDecodeErrors throughout my site and I failed to find the reason for the mismatch.
Neither setting `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` for Apache or `charset utf-8;` for Nginx solved the issue.

Comment: The webserver is run as a separate user. You'll have set that user's locale. A more robust approach would be not to rely on the locale anyway; declare encoding explicitly when opening files, de-/encoding streams etc. In each case ask yourself who should control the choice of encoding: the environment (possibly causing encoding errors at runtime if the environment's choices are unwise), or your interface?

Comment: I will try de-/encoding by hand. Still, Apache and Nginx are run by www-data, which has the same locales.

Comment: Sounds odd. I have to admit, though, that I don't understand every detail of how Python arrives at its default encodings for I/O. Which for me has been just another reason not to rely on them.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was hidden in `/etc/apache2/envvars`:

```
## The locale used by some modules like mod_dav
export LANG=C
## Uncomment the following line to use the system default locale instead:
. /etc/default/locale
```